# Can WebRTC Stream the data I need?

Tags: webrtc

My app is attempting to stream real time proprietary data between two users.

The requirements for the data to be considered real time is that the delay between sending and receiving is less than 200ms.

The data is also packetized, I need to send a packet every 20ms.

Each packet is 300 bytes in size.

Can i stream real time data at 15kbps with a latency of less than 200ms?

Many thanks in advance

Comment: yes, at least in browser, it is possible using  `RTCDataChannel`

Answer (score 0):

The ping depends on how far your other endpoint is and what you bandwidth is.

I experienced a maximum ping of 70ms to a friend of mine between Germany and Austria, so 200ms seems to be realistic.